# insert items to Top from list to the same list after filtering

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to filter items from list and than trying to insert the filtered items to the top of the same list but the list doesn't get updated.

```
// listItems contains 132 items 
// topmakes contains 10 items
var topmakes = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting(
    "RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes")
        .Split('|').ToList().ConvertAll(d=>d.ToLower());

// getting all the makes from the listItems
// filteredMakes also contain 10 items after matching
var filteredMakes = listItems
    .Where(x => topmakes.Any(y => y.Contains(x.Text.ToLower())));

// after this statement listItems still contains 132 items 
// and the 10 items are not added to the list.
listItems.ToList().InsertRange(0, filteredMakes.ToList());
```

Comment: With `listItems.ToList()` you create a new instance of list which go into nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var items = listItems.ToList();
items.InsertRange(0, filteredMakes.ToList());

//do something with items variable, not listItems
```

as @fenixil says, ToList create new instance, so you need to assign it to use it.

or

```
listItems = listItems.Concat(filteredMakes);
```

use Concat in System.Linq

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The problem is the extra `ToList()`.

It should be:
`listItems.InsertRange(0, filteredMakes.ToList());`

*However this will create duplicates as the items are added to the beginning of the list, but not removed from their original spots.*

## Solutions

### A. Add + Insert(0

You could create a new list and then enumerate the original list and call `Add` or `Instert(0, ...)` depending if the model is a top model or not.

### B. Order by

Option 2. You could order the list by 'does_it_belong_to_top_models'

```
var l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var supers = new List<int>() { 2, 5 };

var ordered = l1.OrderBy(i1 => supers.Any(i2 => i1 == i2) ? -1 : 1 );

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ordered));
```

Output

```
2,5,1,3,4,6
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am trying to filter items from list and than trying to insert the filtered items to the top of the same list."*

It sounds like what you really want to do is order the list in such a way that the "top makes" are at the beginning of the list.

To do this, we can use the `OrderByDescending` extension method, and pass it the criteria for what we want at the top.

Given your sample code, I believe it would look something like:

```
var topMakes = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings
    .GetSetting("RACQ.JoinMembership.Top10CarMakes")
    .Split('|')
    .Select(topMake => topMake.ToLower());

// Put any of the topMakes items at the beginning of listItems
listItems = listItems
    .OrderByDescending(listItem => topMakes.Any(topMake => 
        topMake.Contains(listItem.Text.ToLower())))
    .ToList();
```